# Run delve inside docker container - debug.test: no such file or directory

Tags: docker, go, remote-debugging, delve

When trying to running delve inside a docker container from an existing project we got this:

```
API server listening at: [::]:4040
could not launch process: fork/exec /go/src/github.com/marcosvpj/rey/debug.test: no such file or directory
could not remove /go/src/github.com/marcosvpj/rey/debug.test: remove /go/src/github.com/marcosvpj/rey/debug.test: no such file or directory
```

Tried to run inside a brand new project, using the same Dockerfile and everything goes right.
Looked for the file - debug.test - and can't find in both containers.

Anybody has any idea to what I need to look for?

The closest I got is in the FAQ its indicate that is needed to use --security-opt=seccomp:unconfined in the docker run. It is not this, since both projects already have this in the docker run command

---

Docker run command:

```
docker run --security-opt=seccomp:unconfined --rm --net="host" -e LOGGER_LEVEL='error' -v `pwd`:/go/src/github.com/marcosvpj/rey -w /go/src/github.com/marcosvpj/rey rey ./hack/check.sh
```

Comment: How are you adding your project to the container? Are you bind mounting it, and can you give the `docker run` command that you're using?

Comment: @SeanKelleher added the command